# Is possible to store & load UITableViewCells & stand-alone nibs from storyboard?

Tags: ipad, xcode4, nib, storyboard, ios5

I have some nibs that are UITableViews & also custom controls. This controls have actions that will launch storyboard sieges.

So, I have 3 normal UIViewControllers that are connected by the storyboard, then some subViews that are composited on top of some of them and from *this subviews* I like to connect the other UIViewControllers.

Is this possible? Everything in the same storyboard? Currently I store in standalone nibs the controls & cells but need manually present the other controllers in the storyboard.